# how to select subset only by [] in r?

Tags: r

```
a<-data.frame(q1=rep(c(1,'A','B'),4),q2=c(1,'A','B','C'),w1=c(1,'A','B','C'))
```

I want to convert the element of `q1,q2` which `!=1` to `0`,and I want to use only `[]`.I believe all the subset can be done by [].

```
a[grep("q\\d",colnames(a),perl=TRUE)!=1,grep("q\\d",colnames(a),perl=TRUE)]<-0
```

but it doesn't work, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create the a numeric index of the column names that start with 'q' followed by numbers ('nm1'), use that to subset the columns in 'a' and assign the values that are not equal to 1 in that subset to 0.

```
nm1 <- grep("q\\d+", names(a))
a[nm1][a[nm1] != 1] <- 0
```

and make sure we have the columns as `character` class by using `stringsAsFactors= FALSE` in the `data.frame`

The above replacement is based on a logical matrix (`a[nm1]!=1`) which may create memory problems if the dataset is really big.  In that case, it is better to loop through the columns and `replace` with 0

```
a[nm1] <- lapply(a[nm1], function(x) replace(x, x!=1, 0))
```

#### data

```
a <- data.frame(q1=rep(c(1,'A','B'),4),q2=c(1,'A','B','C'),
                 w1=c(1,'A','B','C'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply!I never seen df[column][row] like `a[nm1][a[nm1] != 1] <- 0`, before.I only know `df[row,column]`.How do you know this grammar?

Comment: @jackson883 the `a[nm1]` is subsetting the columns.  when we don't specify the row and , by default, it subsets the columns, then we are playing with the subset data, convert it to logical matrix (`a[nm1]!=1`), and use the the TRUE values that corresponds to the values in a[nm1] to assign it to 0.

Comment: i see, if i have more conditions, i can write a[nm1][a[nm1]!=1][a[nm1]>3]<-0,that's cool, then we can do any subset only by []

Comment: @jackson883 The one you showed might be `a[nm1][a[nm1]!=1 & a[nm1] >3] <-  0`, but as I mentioned in the post, it is better to work on vectors by looping rather than creating a big logical matrix for memory efficiency

Comment: ,i want to subset the `q1` column and  with condition `w1==1`.my script:`tt<-a['q1'][a$w1==1]`,but it doesnot work.I think should be ok because by default `a['q1']`subset the column.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you know column names, you can use them for indexing.

```
a<-data.frame(q1=rep(c(1,'A','B'),4), q2=c(1,'A','B','C'),
   w1=c(1,'A','B','C'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

col_n <- c("q1", "q2")
a[, col_n][a[, col_n]!=1]<-0

> a
   q1 q2 w1
1   1  1  1
2   0  0  A
3   0  0  B
4   1  0  C
5   0  1  1
6   0  0  A
7   1  0  B
8   0  0  C
9   0  1  1
10  1  0  A
11  0  0  B
12  0  0  C
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` approach:

```
a<-data.table(q1=rep(c(1,'A','B'),4),q2=c(1,'A','B','C'),w1=c(1,'A','B','C'))

a[,grep("^q", colnames(a), value = T):=lapply(a[,grep("^q", colnames(a), value = T), with = F], function(x) ifelse(x == 1, 1, 0))]

> a
    q1 q2 w1
 1:  1  1  1
 2:  0  0  A
 3:  0  0  B
 4:  1  0  C
 5:  0  1  1
 6:  0  0  A
 7:  1  0  B
 8:  0  0  C
 9:  0  1  1
10:  1  0  A
11:  0  0  B
12:  0  0  C
```